# excel create multiple folders from list based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a proper VBA code to create a batch folders within the folder where the excel file with the code sits based on multiple cell data (columns and rows)

I have have came across this code

```
Sub CreateFolders()

    'Variable definations
    Dim FolderListRange As Range
    Dim FolderRange As Variant
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim ParentFolderPath As String
    
    On Error GoTo Handle
        ' Set the Folder where the individual folders should be created
        ParentFolderPath = "Folders"
    
        Set FolderListRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A64000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    
        For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange
            If FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Continue
    
            FolderName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & FolderRange.Value & "-" & Format(FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    
            If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
                FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
            End If
    
    Continue:
        Next
```

But this one only creates folders from one column in this case A and down. What I need is folders to be created based on values from A2:C2, A3:C3, etc.

Header of the columns are

```
A1  B1  C1
No. Reg MSN
1   XXX 21334
2   xxy 576576
```

So folder structure after createion should be

```
1-XXX-21334
2-XXY-576576
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Try modifying the code you have to loop through column A, combine the three cells into a string variable, and then create the folder. Or use a helper column to combine the three cells for your range and then loop through each cell and create the folder. e.g. `Range("D1").Value = Range("A1").Value & "-" & Range("B1").Value & "-" & Range("C1").Value` ect. ect. ect.

Answer (score 0):

I went the other way.

I have created a preview column with the following "=CONCATENATE(A2,"*",C2,"*",B2,"_",D2)"

and then used the following code to create the folders.

```
Sub MakeFolders()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer

    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

    For c = 1 To maxCols

        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows

            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If

            r = r + 1
        Loop

    Next c

End Sub
```

Tnx for help.

Answer (score 0):

### Create (Sub)folders From Excel Worksheet

I additionally added `Play1` and `Play2` in column `C` and left column `D` empty to get the following folders:

```
C:\Test\Folder A
C:\Test\Folder B
C:\Test\Folder C
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub1
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub2
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub3
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub1
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub2
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub3
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub1
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub2
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub3
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub1\Play1
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub1\Play2
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub2\Play1
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub2\Play2
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub3\Play1
C:\Test\Folder A\Sub3\Play2
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub1\Play1
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub1\Play2
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub2\Play1
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub2\Play2
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub3\Play1
C:\Test\Folder B\Sub3\Play2
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub1\Play1
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub1\Play2
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub2\Play1
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub2\Play2
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub3\Play1
C:\Test\Folder C\Sub3\Play2
```

- Carefully adjust the values in the constants section.
- Only run the first Sub, the rest is being called.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createFolders()

    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test"
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Dim Cols As Variant: Cols = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    Dim Paths As Variant: ReDim Paths(0): Paths(0) = FolderPath
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(UBound(Cols))
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        getColumn Data(j), ws, Cols(j), FirstRow
    Next j
    For j = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        If IsArray(Data(j)) Then
            createPaths(Paths, Data(j))
        End If
    Next j

End Sub

Sub createPaths(ByRef Paths As Variant, Data As Variant)
    Dim NewPaths As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    ReDim NewPaths((UBound(Paths) + 1) * UBound(Data) - 1)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Paths)
        For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
            NewPaths(k) = Paths(j) & Application.PathSeparator & Data(i, 1)
            ' Debug.Print NewPaths(k)
            MkDir NewPaths(k)
            k = k + 1
        Next i
    Next j
    Paths = NewPaths
End Sub

Sub getColumn(ByRef Data As Variant, _
              Sheet As Worksheet, _
              Optional ByVal aColumn As Variant = 1, _
              Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(aColumn).Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Row > FirstRow Then
        Data = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, aColumn), rng)
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
End Sub
```