# Create multiple folders with Excel macros using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help creating a macros for creating multiple folders in User Desktop **MRO_FOLDERS** subfolder.

I have column **Main Folder** with list of main folders. In each **Main Folder** I need to create all subfolders mentioned in column **SubFolder level 1**

[image]

For example: for **Folder A** I need to create

- desktop\Folder A\SUB1
- desktop\Folder A\SUB2
- desktop\Folder A\SUB3

My knowledge of programming is poor. Please see my current version of script below

```
Sub MakeDirs()
Dim Fldrpath As String
    Fldrpath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\"
If Dir(Fldrpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir Fldrpath
End If
For Each cell In Selection
 MkDir Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\" & cell.Value
 MkDir Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\" & cell.Value & "\GANTT Charts"
 MkDir Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\" & cell.Value & "\Induction"
 MkDir Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\" & cell.Value & "\Photos"
 MkDir Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\" & cell.Value & "\Planning Meetings"
Next cell
 'Display Message
    MsgBox "New folder >MRO_FOLDERS< have been created successfully on your Desktop !", vbInformation, "VBAF1"

End Sub
```

Which does the job but I need to edit the macro if I want to add or remove SubFolder Level 1

Comment: I would say that you asked the question properly, but you didn't back it up with any code, like [the last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944085/excel-create-multiple-folders-from-list-based-on-multiple-cell-values/63003519#63003519) so people couldn't see how much effort you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub MakeDirs()
    Dim Fldrpath As String, ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, sf As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Fldrpath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\MRO_FOLDERS\"
    If Dir(Fldrpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir Fldrpath
    End If
    
    'assuming you don't have that second list in Col A
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        MkDir Fldrpath & cell.Value
        'create subfolders
        For Each sf In ws.Range("B2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            MkDir Fldrpath & cell.Value & "\" & sf.Value
        Next sf
    Next cell
    
    'Display Message
    MsgBox "New folder 'MRO_FOLDERS' has been created successfully on your Desktop !", _
                vbInformation, "VBAF1"

End Sub
```